# Relationship between .NET CultureInfo and Android's Locale.Default

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am a bit confused about Xamarin's .NET locale and the Android locale.

**1st question**
I see that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` gets the value of the system's locale (`Locale.Default`).

However, `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` are null.
Does this mean I need to set them myself?

**2nd question**
 in my app, the user is able to change the language. 
Should I only set .NET culture or both the .NET culture and Android `Locale.Default`?

What's the relationship between the .NET and `Locale.Default`?

**3rd question**
Calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I create new XF `Page`, the UI is not localized (I'm using `resx` files as described here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/).
But setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`  does it. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > **1st question** I see that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` gets the value of the system's `locale (Locale.Default)`.
   >   However, `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` are null. Does this mean I need to set them myself?

   If you want to change the culture for your application domain, then yes, you need to set them yourself.

   Referring to [CultureInfo Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#AppDomain):

   > the [DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) properties are static members, **they define the default culture and default UI culture only for the application domain that is current at the time these property values are set.** For more information, see the next section, [Culture and application domains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx#AppDomain).
2. > **2nd question** in my app, the user is able to change the language. Should I only set .NET culture or both the .NET culture and Android Locale.Default?
   >
   > What's the relationship between the .NET and Locale.Default?

   `java.util.Locale` defines the culture information in the following format:

   **`<language code>[_<country code>[_<variant code>]]`**

   For details of `java.util.locale`, please refer to [Understanding Locale in the Java Platform](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html).

   `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` is defined based on RFC 4646 in following format:

   **`languagecode2>-country/regioncode2`**

   So the difference is they uses different separator:`-` and `_`.
3. > **3rd question** Calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I create new XF Page, the UI is not localized (I'm using resx files as described here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/). But setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` does it. Why?

   **`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is readonly.** Calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` doesn't change the culture in current app domain. But setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` does.

Comment: @Don Box, Any Updates?

Comment: Thanks, sorry for delay